# Thinner html canvas stroke width

Tags: html, canvas, stroke

I have set the `2d context` line width to its apparent minimum 1:

```
  let context = this._canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.stroke();
```

But that is still fairly wide : maybe 20 pixels. Is there any way to get it less?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, check that the canvas's attributes width and height match the CSS ones. The canvas looks very stretched. (larger css size than actual)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to ensuring that you've the same number of virtual pixels as you have actual ones. More screen pixels and the image is scaled larger. Fewer screen pixels and the image is shrunk.
Scaling up a 1 pixel wide line produces rectangles, but what happens when we scale down a 1 pixel line? The simple answer is it becomes less intense.

The following example draws 2 canvases the same size. The key difference though, is the size of the pixel buffer they each have. The first has 10,000 pixels - 100x100. The second has just 100 pixels - 10x10. Even though we've just drawn a 1 pixel wide line, you can see the very different appearances of these lines.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);
function onLoaded(evt)
{
  let can = document.querySelector('canvas');
  let ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(can.width,can.height);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  let can2 = document.querySelectorAll('canvas')[1];
  let ctx2 = can2.getContext('2d');
  ctx2.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx2.lineTo(can2.width,can2.height);
  ctx2.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<canvas width=100 height=100></canvas><br>
<canvas width=10 height=10></canvas>
```

Comment: The width and height of the canvas are determined by our data constraints and can not be changed to satisfy the `stroke` width.  Is there an alternate mechanism to reduce that width? i  am upvoting for the useful info in any case

Comment: Uh-huh. Create a much larger canvas and then show it at reduced size. Shown at the right size, the green line in your example image would be 1 pixel wide on the screen. It's 20 pixels wide at the moment? Either display it at 1/20 of the size (unlikely to be useful) or create a canvas that's 20 (x20=400) times larger. Think about the "Quick, Fast, Good - Pick any two" saying. A tradeoff that may or may not matter has to be made somewhere. You can draw it accurately or pleasingly it seems. I'd consider making both viewing modes available. Without more detail, I can't think what to suggest.